# JAVA - unMarshaller not returning same object - code example

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying a test code for Marshaller and unMarshaller on a simple java class.

I create my object and set its ID. problem encountered  is after unMarshalling it back to a java object the ID variable isn't the same...

My questions are :

1. Why isn't this working and both objects don't have the same ID ?
2. My java class has to have a set method for all variables ? or does Marshaller use a different way to update the class variables ?

This is my code snippet :

```
package test;


import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.junit.Test;

public class test {

    @Test
    public void marshallingTest() throws JAXBException{

        // Create a JAXB context passing in the class of the object we want to marshal/unmarshal
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JavaObject.class);

        // Create the marshaller
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        // Create a stringWriter to hold the XML
        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        // Create my java object
        final JavaObject javaObject = new JavaObject();

        // set the objects ID
        javaObject.setId(90210);

        // Marshal the javaObject and write the XML to the stringWriter
        marshaller.marshal(javaObject, stringWriter);

        // Print out the contents of the stringWriter
        System.out.println("First object :");
        System.out.println(javaObject.toString());

        // Create the unmarshaller
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        // Unmarshal the XML 
        final JavaObject javaObject2 = (JavaObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(stringWriter.toString()));

        //print the new object
        System.out.println("Second object after unmarshaller :");
        System.out.println(javaObject2.toString());
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    private static class JavaObject {
        private int id;

        public JavaObject() {
        }

        private int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        private void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id = "+id;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output :

```
First object :
id = 90210
Second object after unmarshaller :
id = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will treat all public fields and properties as mapped.  Your accessor (get/set) methods should be `public`, you currently have them as `private`.  Or you can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class, this tells JAXB to map the fields which may be private.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@XmlElement    
private void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @XmlRootElement 
    private static class JavaObject {
         @XmlElement 
        private int id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which fields is part of the xml structure.

you can either add `@XmlElement` as already suggested by previous answers or use the `@XmlACcessorType` annotation:

```
  @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  private static class JavaObject {
  }
```

This will by default access all the fields of your class